# some thread never exit by itself

Tags: python, multithreading

it's a similar source I've uploaded yesterday but solve some problems thanks to your help.

it's a little bit shame asking another question about somewhat same problem:(

but though I deliberated what is the problem all day,I failed to find. So,

it looks good and do work,but the problem is, some thread never terminate themselves for a long time.

I waited even 10 minutes but 6 threads are still alive.

it's the biggest mystery thing since I started learing programming...

would you please teach me what's wrong with it?

```
import os 
import threading 
import multiprocessing 


def finder(path, q, done): 
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(unicode(path)): 
        for dirname in dirs: 
            if target in dirname.lower(): 
                q.put(os.path.join(root,dirname)) 
        for name in files: 
            if target in name.lower(): 
                q.put(os.path.join(root,name)) 
    #print "good bye",threading.current_thread()
    #print threading.active_count()
    done.put(1) 

def printer(q,done,worker_count): 
    total = 0 
    while 1: 
        try: done.get_nowait() 
        except: pass 
        else: total += 1 

        try: tmp=q.get(timeout=1) 
        except: pass 
        else: print tmp            

        if total == worker_count: 
            break 



if __name__ =="__main__": 

    results = multiprocessing.Queue() 
    done = multiprocessing.Queue() 


    root, dirs, files = os.walk(u"C:\\").next() 
    for dirname in dirs: 
        if target in dirname.lower(): 
            q.put(os.path.join(root,dirname)) 
    for name in files: 
        if target in name.lower(): 
            q.put(os.path.join(root,name)) 

    thnum=len(dirs) 
    target=raw_input("what you wanna get\n") 


    for i in xrange(thnum): 
        full_path = os.path.join(root, dirs[i]) 
        t=threading.Thread(target=finder,args=(full_path, results, done,)) 
        t.start() 

    p=multiprocessing.Process(target=printer,args=(results,done,thnum,)) 
    p.start() 


    p.join()
```

Comment: It could be that it really takes that much longer. For example large cache folders from mail clients like thunderbird or outlook express, and from web browsers, may make this take very long (????) Or you could be looking at cycles somehow. Can you build in code somehow to signal the existing threads that they should print out their status?

Comment: by comparing the result with that of my another program, it just find all the file but the thread just stop but not exit...

Comment: Um… you're walking the filesystem and putting every file in the tree into the queue, and then for each file in the queue you're walking the entire tree again and pushing every file in that tree into the queue. All this pointless repetition is going to take a very, very long time for even a modest subtree.

Comment: Actually, hold on a sec… you're using target without ever defining it. So, unless your C: drive is completely empty, this is obviously not the code you're running, because this code will throw a NameError and quit immediately.

Comment: can you try and run in a shallower and overseeable subdirectory, instead of your hard disk's root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ First, of course, I had to make some trivial changes to make this code 'compile']

The good news is: it just works as you think it should work. Well done. The bad news is: it doesn't work as fast as you had expected.

On my machine, running it on my home directory alone already takes approx 10 minutes:

```
[andre@hp ~]$ time python snippet.py
what you wanna get
test.txt
... results removed ...

real        9m39.083s
user        0m30.368s
sys         0m22.664s
[andre@hp ~]$
```

The question is whether implementing this in processes and threads is a good idea. I think not. Chances are the performance suffers from this massive multithreading.

Comment: I finally make it work with coroutine. make a connection with coroutine instead of using "done" with Queue.put, but it just 2 seconds faster:( I agree with you. it was not a good idea. thank you!